# Apostrophe in word in c++ translator progam

Tags: c++, oop, header-files, translators

I'm writing a program for a translator. Now, i'm a writing a class for words and it is as follows, i'm having trouble writing the method to return all the words with an apostrophe in a sentence.
What should i write after bool Words::isApostophePresent(){

if(.....)

```
 Words::Words() {}

string Words::getWord(){
      return word;
}

void Words::setWord(string w){
     word=w;
}

int Words::getNumCharacters(){
   return word.length();
}

vector<char> Words::getCharacters(){
      int numChars=word.length();
      for (int i=0;i<numChars;i++){
           characters.push_back(word[i]);
      }
      return characters;
}

bool Words::isFirstCharacterUppercase(){

   if(isupper(word[0])){
      firstCharacterUppercase=1;
   }
   else {
      firstCharacterUppercase=0;
   }
   return firstCharacterUppercase;
}

bool Words::isApostophePresent(){

   if()





}
Words::~Words(){}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

const std::string STR1 = "Hello'World";
const std::string STR2 = "Hello World";

bool hasApostrophe(const std::string& s){ 
  return s.find("'", 0, 1) != std::string::npos; 
}

int main(int, char**){

    std::cout << STR1 << " has apostrophe = " << hasApostrophe(STR1) << '\n';
    std::cout << STR2 << " has apostrophe = " << hasApostrophe(STR2) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I just started this this year, and I dnt know how to  include the answer you gave me i my code above. Could anyone help? or give another answer for the above question.

Comment: The hasApostrophe function when passed a string returns true when the string contains an apostrophe and false otherwise. Simply paste that function into your file (at the top somewhere) and call it with the string you wish to test. Not sure I can explain it any more than that.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your answer. Actually it is for a translator program and I dont have any specific string to use to find the apostrophe. Thanks again for the help. I'll try it